# How to customise songs package - Change the format of titles, verses, choruses, etc

Tags: songs, leadsheets

I am writing a songbook with chords in latex using the songs package. Though very nice package I don't like the default theme.

[image: the default theme for the songs package]

This was created with the minimal working example (MWE)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, twoside, onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
% \includeonlysongs{2}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.1in}
\settowidth{\versenumwidth}{1.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
\newauthorindex{authidx}{cbauth}
\newscripindex{scripidx}{cbscrip}

\begin{document}

\showindex{Complete Index of Songs}{titleidx}

\songsection{Worship Songs}
\begin{songs}{titleidx,authidx,scripidx}
\beginsong{Doxology}[
  by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
  sr={Revelation 5:13},
  cr={Public domain.},
  index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse*
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{And Can It Be}[
  by={Charles Wesley and Thomas Campbell},
  sr={Romans 8:1; Philippians 2:6-8; 1 Thessalonians 5:9},
  cr={Public domain.},
  index={Amazing love! How can it be}]
\beginverse
\[F]And \[F/A]can \[(C)]it \[F]be that \[Gm/B&]I \[C7]should \[F]gain
An \[B&]in\[C]terest \[F/A]in \[C/E]the \[C/G]Sav\[G7]ior's \[C]blood?
Died He \[F/C]for me, \[C] who \[F/A]caused \[F]His \[C]pain?
For \[B&]me, who \[F/A]Him \[(Gm/B&)]to \[F/C]death \[C7]pur\[F]sued?
A\[C]mazing \[F/A]love! \[C/G]How \[B&]can \[G7/B]it \[C]be
That \[F]Thou, my \[B&]God, shouldst \[C C7]die for \[F]me?
\endverse
\beginchorus
Amazing \[C]love! How \[C7/E]can it \[F]be
That \[B&]Thou, my \[F/A]God, \[Gm/B&]shouldst \[F/C]die \[C7]for \[F]me?
\endchorus
\endsong

\beginscripture{Romans 8:3-4}
For what the law was powerless to do in that it was weakened by the sinful nature, God did by sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful man to be a sin offering. And so he condemned sin in sinful man, in order that the righteous requirements of the law might be fully met in us, who do not live according to the sinful nature but according to the Spirit.
\endscripture
\end{songs}

\showindex{Index of Authors and Composers}{authidx}
\showindex{Index of Scripture}{scripidx}

\end{document}
```

How can I change the font of the chords? it's too big right now for my taste

How can I make the whole document one column? I tried to define onecolumn through the memoir package but did not do anything

How can I change the template for the title of songs?

All these formatting questions. I have some experience with Latex. but not by redefining commands.

On the other hand there is another CTAN package: leadsheets that claims to be easier to customise. But can we easily create indices by author, indices by other tags of songs such as in this case the scripture reference, indices for the first verse of a song, like we can for the songs package?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/songs/songs.pdf) of the `songs` package provides this information. Section 11.2 defines various formatting commands, such as `\printchord` (chord appearance) and `\stitlefont` (song titles), and many others. The manual also provides examples on how to use/redefine these commands. The columns are described in Section 11.5, in particular the `\songcolumns` command.

MWE, with the formatting commands just before `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, twoside, onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \includeonlysongs{2}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.1in}
\settowidth{\versenumwidth}{1.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
\newauthorindex{authidx}{cbauth}
\newscripindex{scripidx}{cbscrip}

\songcolumns{1}
\renewcommand{\printchord}[1]{\sffamily\small#1}
\renewcommand{\stitlefont}{
\rmfamily\Large\bfseries\color{blue}\baselineskip=20pt\lineskiplimit=0pt
}
\begin{document}

\showindex{Complete Index of Songs}{titleidx}

\songsection{Worship Songs}
\begin{songs}{titleidx,authidx,scripidx}
\beginsong{Doxology}[
  by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
  sr={Revelation 5:13},
  cr={Public domain.},
  index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse*
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{And Can It Be}[
  by={Charles Wesley and Thomas Campbell},
  sr={Romans 8:1; Philippians 2:6-8; 1 Thessalonians 5:9},
  cr={Public domain.},
  index={Amazing love! How can it be}]
\beginverse
\[F]And \[F/A]can \[(C)]it \[F]be that \[Gm/B&]I \[C7]should \[F]gain
An \[B&]in\[C]terest \[F/A]in \[C/E]the \[C/G]Sav\[G7]ior's \[C]blood?
Died He \[F/C]for me, \[C] who \[F/A]caused \[F]His \[C]pain?
For \[B&]me, who \[F/A]Him \[(Gm/B&)]to \[F/C]death \[C7]pur\[F]sued?
A\[C]mazing \[F/A]love! \[C/G]How \[B&]can \[G7/B]it \[C]be
That \[F]Thou, my \[B&]God, shouldst \[C C7]die for \[F]me?
\endverse
\beginchorus
Amazing \[C]love! How \[C7/E]can it \[F]be
That \[B&]Thou, my \[F/A]God, \[Gm/B&]shouldst \[F/C]die \[C7]for \[F]me?
\endchorus
\endsong

\beginscripture{Romans 8:3-4}
For what the law was powerless to do in that it was weakened by the sinful nature, God did by sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful man to be a sin offering. And so he condemned sin in sinful man, in order that the righteous requirements of the law might be fully met in us, who do not live according to the sinful nature but according to the Spirit.
\endscripture
\end{songs}

\showindex{Index of Authors and Composers}{authidx}
\showindex{Index of Scripture}{scripidx}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]